# Androidx Navigation icon compatability issues in Android 7

Tags: android, kotlin, icons, toolbar

I am using com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout along with androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar in my app and in Android 8 it works perfectly but I am having an issue where the 'hamburger' menu icon and 'back' icons are just displaying as a white block in android 7 (API 24 & API 25) even though other menu icons are displayed correctly.

Where the hamburger icon is showing.

[image: where the hamburger icon looks like]

And what the back button looks like.

[image: what the back button looks like]

My app bar layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_drawer_layout_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And just setting up the toolbar:

```
setSupportActionBar ( toolbar )

    actionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
    actionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
    actionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    actionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    actionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
```

Comment: @tynn I have yes. Like I said on later versions it displays perfectly. so far the issue seems to be api 24 and api 25

Comment: Are you using color filter or tint? In code, in styles or in layout?

Comment: It looks like it's applying a filter or tint as @crysxd said, these are handled differently in older versions of Android, so it's a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Material library this is the expected result. I don't know how the compiler in Android 8 override the material theme settings by default. If you use material library color tints are by default applied. For more details have a look at **https://material.io/design/color/applying-color-to-ui.html#usage**.
You will learn everything about Material library at that website.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply tint or background color in theme.

If you not able to find the problem -> add ImageView(for back button) inside Toolbar

ex:

```
<Toolbar>
   <ImageView>
 </Toolbar>
```